# Local jar doesn't get picked up properly

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-ws, wildfly-10

I've generated a webservice consumer with Jax-ws and packaged it into a jar-file using maven. I want to use this jar-file in a different project so that I can talk to the webservice from this other project. I added the dependency using maven and a local repository like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.vrt</groupId>
        <artifactId>ScheduAllClient</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>data-local</id>
        <name>data</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I run my project using spring boot in IntelliJ, I can talk to the WS without any problem. If I then package the project into a war-file and try to deploy on Wildfly, I get following error:

```
Cannot upload deployment: {
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./sa-integrations" 
    => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./sa-integrations: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'KPSController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kpsImportTask'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'KPSImportTask': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'saService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SAService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'resourceDAO'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduAllService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduAllServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type. Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'KPSController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kpsImportTask'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'KPSImportTask': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'saService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SAService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'resourceDAO'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduAllService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduAllServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type. 
    Caused by: 
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'KPSController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kpsImportTask'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'KPSImportTask': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'saService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SAService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'resourceDAO'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduAllService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduAllServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type. 
    Caused by: 
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'KPSImportTask': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'saService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SAService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'resourceDAO'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduAllService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduAllServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type. 
    Caused by: 
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SAService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'resourceDAO'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduAllService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduAllServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type. 
    Caused by: 
        org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'scheduAllService'; 
        nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduAllServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type. 
    Caused by: 
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduAllServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; 
        nested exception is org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type. 
    Caused by: 
        org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Part Body defined with no element and no type."
},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
    "jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./sa-integrations"
],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}
```

The ScheduAllServiceImpl looks like this:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("ScheduAllService")
public class ScheduAllServiceImpl {
    @WebServiceRef(SchedWebServiceAPI.class)
    private SchedWebServiceAPISoap schedWebServiceAPISoap;
```

SchedWebServiceAPI.class is the main class of the required jar.

Does anybody know what is going wrong? I guess it has something to do with maven. I've tried packaging with `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package` but nothing seems to work. When I check the war-file, the required jar file is present in WEB-INF/lib.

If it may be of any help, I'm using:

- Maven 3.2.1
- JDK 1.8
- Wildfly 10.1.0

Comment: Why do you assume it's not getting picked up? Maven throws an explicit error when it can't find a dependency (which I don't see here). Perhaps do a Maven run with -X just to make sure it is getting picked up from the location you think it should be picked up?

Comment: It is getting picked up, I tried using -X and everything looks fine, the jar get's included. I was assuming it had something to do with maven since it runs perfectly fine in IntelliJ without building the war, but when I build the war and try to deploy it, it suddenly gives me these errors..

Comment: It looks like something with Spring isn't configured correctly. This doesn't look like a Maven or WildFly issue.

Comment: Hmm, would you have any idea where to start to look for it? The only thing spring does with this api is what you see right there. A little further in this class it just calls 1 method in the api: schedWebServiceAPISoap.xmlSchedRemoteCompoundCommand(). So apart from that Spring isn't much involved in the process I guess...